# dynamically change stock quantity depending on selected options

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, e-commerce, product

I am currently working on a project to create an e-commerce website.
Here's the problem:
I'm in the product page and there is an availability input which indicates if a product is available or not
there is also several select (depending on the product category) to filtre the product for exemple 3 select one for color the other for size the other for design

My question is: How can i change the availabily input depending on what the user selects in those 3 select options **KNOWING THAT !**  the user can select only one if he wants to and leave the other 2 select blank and the availability input would still be showing the data

PS: My database is already working and i can do what ever query is possible. My only problem was how to code this using ajax and php, if the user selected all the options to show the availability, i can do that but i want him to choose whatever combination he wants in the filtre.
**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: Do you mean you are not familiar with AJAX or you don't know what to query?

Comment: @RST i'm not familiar with AJAX

Comment: The idea of AJAX is to make a call in the script, sending `form` information to a .php file. The php file will contact the database, fiddle with the results and return them. Then the AJAX call performs actions dependent on the results. Read up on the matter, post your form code and AJAX code if you get stuck.